# I'm Looking for a sample CSV product file to import into test store

Tags: magento-1, import, csv, importexport

I have my first Magento test site running and I'm looking for a sample CSV product file to import for testing. Does anybody know where I can download one? Ideally I'd like the file to contain lots of items so I can test the speed of search.

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: try to add new product properly and than you can get sample CSV from import/export option in system menu

Comment: Is this for M1 or M2?

Answer (score 1):

You can find Magento 2 Default CSV sample files for import on https://github.com/firebearstudio/magento2-import-export-sample-files

Also it can be downloaded on System -> Import next to entity selection dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

This is quiet old, but hey ...

## [Compressed Magento 1.9 Sample Data](https://github.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data)

> The following variations are available:
>
> - 66M [compressed-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tgz](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/1.9.1.0/compressed-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tgz)
> - 65M [compressed-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tbz](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/1.9.1.0/compressed-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tbz)
> - 40M [compressed-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tar.7z](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/1.9.1.0/compressed-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tar.7z)
> - 26M [compressed-no-mp3-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tgz](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/1.9.1.0/compressed-no-mp3-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tgz)
> - 25M [compressed-no-mp3-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tbz](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/1.9.1.0/compressed-no-mp3-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tbz)
> - 19M [compressed-no-mp3-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tar.7z](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/1.9.1.0/compressed-no-mp3-magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tar.7z)
>
> Its kind of ridiculous having a sample data package that is 317MB in
>   size, and since I couldn't find a good alternative source, I decided
>   to hack together a little script to compress the hell out of the
>   images and the MP3 files in the sample data archive.   My intention is
>   that it can be downloaded faster and used more easily.
>
> With a image quality setting of 50% and by sampling all .mp3 files
>   down to a bitrate of 48, the size of the sample data archive is
>   reduced to a 66MB tbz.
>
> The compression script in the src/ directory is intended to run on OS
>   X. Feel free to use and modify it, but be aware that you are doing so
>   at your own risk!
>
> Please check the 1.9.0.0 branch for the previous version of the sample
>   data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Magento sample data could be a solution to your problem. But you may have to reinstall your database (if you made database changes with installer scripts, it should be fine, otherwise it might be lost.

You can find documentation about it there, depending of your version :
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ht_magento-ce-sample.data.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html